# when remove nodes with low degrees, why some with high degrees have been also deleted from graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I tried to remove nodes with low degrees, to simplify my gragh. Here is the code:

```
low_degree_node = [x for x in g.nodes() if g.degree(x) <= 50]
g.remove_nodes_from(low_degree_node)
```

But when I checked whether it works, I found that some high-degree nodes were deleted too.
Below is my check node:

```
degree_sequence = sorted((d for n, d in g.degree()), reverse=True)
dmax = max(degree_sequence)
dmin = min(degree_sequence)
print(dmin)
print(dmax)
```

The whole code:

```
# before remove
degree_sequence = sorted((d for n, d in g.degree()), reverse=True)
dmax = max(degree_sequence)
dmin = min(degree_sequence)
print(dmin)
print(dmax)

low_degree_node = [x for x in g.nodes() if g.degree(x) <= 50]
g.remove_nodes_from(low_degree_node)

# after remove
degree_sequence = sorted((d for n, d in g.degree()), reverse=True)
dmax = max(degree_sequence)
dmin = min(degree_sequence)
print(dmin)
print(dmax)
```

The results are:

```
# before
2
398
# after
41
363
```

What's wrong with it? And how could I remove low-degree nodes?

Comment: Deleting nodes is going to reduce the degree of the remaining nodes that were connected to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to claim without a reproducible example, but it seems that the low-degree nodes were connected to the highest degree node (so it was a star), as a result the highest degree node is still in the graph, but has a lower degree (since it lost some of the connected low-degree nodes).

Comment: I tried to trace the node with the highest degree, and indeed its degree dropped. Thank you for your answer.